# How to fix an error associating with a comparator?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, queue, g++, comparator

The code is compiled, and run without any issue in CLion IDE with g++ compiler in MinGW, however, the same exact code has a compilation error in Visual Studio IDE and with (MSVC compiler)

I believe the error should have to do with the follwoing comparator class:

```
struct CompareVertices {
    inline bool operator()(shared_ptr<Vertex> a, shared_ptr<Vertex> b) const {
        return a->get_distance() < b->get_distance() ? false : true;
    }
};
```

which later has been made use of in:

```
 priority_queue<shared_ptr<Vertex>, vector<shared_ptr<Vertex>>, CompareVertices> pQ;
```

I get the following error (**Only** in *VS 2019 (MSVC)*  and **no error** in *Clion(MinGW)*):

```
File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xutility
Line: 1520
Expression: invalid comparator

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to debug the application)
'practice_Classes.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll'. 
'practice_Classes.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. 
'practice_Classes.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. 
'practice_Classes.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. 
'practice_Classes.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll'. 
'practice_Classes.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. 
'practice_Classes.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll'. 
'practice_Classes.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll'. 
'practice_Classes.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. 
'practice_Classes.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. 
'practice_Classes.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\TextShaping.dll'. 
'practice_Classes.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll'. 
'practice_Classes.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'. 
'practice_Classes.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll'. 
'practice_Classes.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. 
'practice_Classes.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. 
'practice_Classes.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll'. 
'practice_Classes.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\TextInputFramework.dll'. 
'practice_Classes.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\CoreMessaging.dll'. 
'practice_Classes.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\CoreUIComponents.dll'. 
'practice_Classes.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\SHCore.dll'. 
'practice_Classes.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll'. 
'practice_Classes.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntmarta.dll'. 
'practice_Classes.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. 
'practice_Classes.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\WinTypes.dll'.
```

**Network.h**

```
using namespace std;
typedef long double ld;
class Arc; // forward declaration

class Vertex {

private:
    string name_{ "" };
    long double dist_{ numeric_limits<long double>::infinity() }; 
    shared_ptr<Vertex> prev_{ nullptr };
    bool visited_{ false };
    vector<shared_ptr<Vertex>> adjacent_vertices_;
    vector<shared_ptr<Arc>> adjacent_arcs_;

public:

    Vertex() = default;
    Vertex(string name) : name_(name)
    {
    }
    ~Vertex() = default;


    Vertex(const Vertex& cpyObj) :
        name_(cpyObj.name_),
        dist_(cpyObj.dist_),
        visited_(cpyObj.visited_),
        adjacent_vertices_(cpyObj.adjacent_vertices_),
        adjacent_arcs_(cpyObj.adjacent_arcs_)
    {
        prev_ = make_shared<Vertex>(name_);
    }

    Vertex(Vertex&& moveObj) noexcept :
        name_(move(moveObj.name_)),
        dist_(move(moveObj.dist_)),
        prev_(move(moveObj.prev_)),
        visited_(move(moveObj.visited_)),
        adjacent_vertices_(move(moveObj.adjacent_vertices_)),
        adjacent_arcs_(move(moveObj.adjacent_arcs_))
    {
        moveObj.prev_ = nullptr;
    }


    // some setter and getter functions  including the follwoing two:
    inline void set_prev(shared_ptr<Vertex> ptr) { this->prev_ = ptr; }
    inline auto get_prev() const { return prev_; }
   
};
```

then:

```
struct CompareVertices {
    bool operator()(shared_ptr<Vertex> a, shared_ptr<Vertex> b) const {
        return a->get_distance() < b->get_distance() ? false : true;
    }
};


class Arc {

private:
    shared_ptr<Vertex> from_{ nullptr };
    shared_ptr<Vertex> to_{ nullptr };
    long double arc_length_{ 0 };

public:

Arc() = default;
Arc(shared_ptr<Vertex> from, shared_ptr<Vertex> to, long double length) : arc_length_(length)
{
    this->from_ = from;
    this->to_ = to;
}
~Arc() = default;

// some setter and getter and output stream functions here   
};

class Network {

private:

    vector<shared_ptr<Vertex>> Vertices_;
    vector<shared_ptr<Arc>> Arcs_;

public:

    Network() = default;
    Network(vector<shared_ptr<Vertex>>& Vertices, vector<shared_ptr<Arc>>& Arcs) : Vertices_(Vertices), Arcs_(Arcs) {}
    ~Network() = default;

// also some setter and getter plus some other utility functions here

};



class Dijkstras_Alg
{
private:
    shared_ptr<Vertex> source_node_{ nullptr };
    shared_ptr<Vertex> destin_node_{ nullptr };
    shared_ptr<Network> Ntwk_{ nullptr };

public:

    Dijkstras_Alg() = default;
    Dijkstras_Alg(shared_ptr<Vertex> src, shared_ptr<Vertex> destin, shared_ptr<Network> Ntwk) {
        cout << "Dijkstra construction running\n";
        this->source_node_ = src;
        this->destin_node_ = destin;
        this->Ntwk_ = Ntwk;
    }
    ~Dijkstras_Alg() = default;

// some setter and getter and utility functions here 

    void compute_path() {
        std::priority_queue< std::shared_ptr<Vertex>, std::vector<shared_ptr<Vertex> >, CompareVertices > pQ;
        source_node_->set_distance(0);
        pQ.push(source_node_);
        while (!pQ.empty())
        {
                    // arcs relaxation is done here
                pQ.pop();
                current_vertex->set_visited();
            }
    
        }  
    };
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfp63.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jx91K.png)

this is printed: *Dijkstra construction running*, and then the error is popping up!

Any workaround?

PS:

1. it is not due to "inline" keyword
2. the program works perfectly in CLion with g++ compiler (with or without the copy constructor and move constructor)

Comment: This is the cool thing about Undefined Behaviour: The implementer gets a lot of leeway to do whatever they want. In the debug Standard Library that comes with Visual Studio the crafty coders have added in a check to make sure the comparator is valid strict-weak ordering. The default Standard Library implementation that comes with g++ and the Release libraries that come with Visual Studio save time by performing absolutely no checking and let the invalid comparator produce invalid sorted output. In other words, the comparator is still wrong in g++, you just don't get warned.

Comment: `return a->get_distance() < b->get_distance() ? false : true;` -- What if `a->get_distance()` == `b->get_distance()`?  You return `true`.  Meaning that item `a` will be placed before `b`.  However, what if `b->get_distance()` == `a->get_distance()`?  You return `true`, meaning item `b` is placed before `a`.  So which one is it, does item `a` get placed before item `b`, or does item `b` get placed before item `a`?  That is exactly how Visual C++ works in debug mode, and can detect that your comparison is faulty.  It calls your operator() twice with the values switched, and checks return values.

Comment: Also, for g++, the code does not work "perfectly".  The behavior is undefined if the sort criteria is faulty.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks, you are right, following your comment I modified the comparator to return `return (a->get_distance() < b->get_distance());` and the error's just gone away. Now, I just wonder why (1) g++ did not throw any error or exception? (2) in the priority _queue based on the documentation, the greater the value the higher the priority, but in Dijkstra we are seeking for the lower the value (distance) the higher the priority. If we don't explicitly define it in our comparator, how the compiler would prioritize?

Comment: @BMB Undefined behavior means that anything can happen.  It is just that Visual C++ in debug mode does the check.  Run the code in release mode in VC++, and you will get different results (no popup message box).

Comment: 1) see top two comments. g++ gives no warning because it's not required to. The warning is a bone thrown to you by those fine folks at Microsoft.

Comment: 2) The compiler can't prioritize. You MUST provide a comparator that provides the ordering you require.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I got your points Paul, thanks. But, in my comparator, I had not written `<=` , and it was only `<`. @WhozCraig explanations in the comment section was even better than the one as the accepted answer. I gather that I only need to specify the condition only. Well, based off your comment, I believe I might need to set an appropriate tolerance, e.g., EPSILON, like `return ((a->get_distance()  < b_get_distance() - EPS) && (std::abs(a_get_distance() - b_get_distance() > EPS)))` . Is that right?

Comment: How you craft your comparator is entirely up to you, but it must purely answer the question being asked ( `a<b`, e.g. is `a` strictly less than `b`, in whatever context you choose to see it). If that is true, it *must* be impossible for `b < a` to also be true. If both are false then the objects are considered equivalent. Further when you said, *"But, in my comparator, I had not written <="* , yes you did, you just didn't realize it, as explained in my answer.

Comment: @BMB -- *But, in my comparator, I had not written <=* -- I never mentioned that you wrote `<=`.  I stated the scenario to you as to why Visual C++ detected the error and how it detects these errors.  Again, it called your comparison twice, first with `a,b` and then with `b,a`.  You returned the same value each time, thus the ambiguousness of which item is placed before the other item, and thus the `Expression: invalid comparator` error you received.  You can debug into the `std::sort` comparison code in the `<algorithm>` header and see this in action.

Comment: @user4581301 -- _This is the cool thing about Undefined Behaviour_ -- I was totally wrong! Then, I should be thankful for the compiler error in VS rather than being glad that g++ had compiled the code and "amazingly" returned the correct solution!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You are right. I see the point now, I appreciate it!

Comment: @BMB I usually compile and test my stuff with a few different development environments to see if one of them makes a mistake easier to spot through a compiler warning or visible misbehaviour when executed.

Comment: @user4581301 It seems to be the only right way when it comes to C++. Had I only stuck to Clion with g++, I would never know of this error!

Comment: YOu would have seen the bug eventually, but this warning is a LOT better. Sooner or later someone would have given an input that resulting in visibly a bad ordering or an infinite loop of placing A before B and then placing B before A. Hours of debugging later you'd have figured out the problem, but if you knew basically what to look for right from the get go... More time for whatever hobbies you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your somewhat odd comparator...

```
return a->get_distance() < b->get_distance() ? false : true;
```

is effectively this:

```
return a->get_distance() >= b->get_distance();
```

The problem is that `>=`, and specifically the equivalence inclusion of that operation. That does *not* enforce a strict-weak ordering. Equivalence should not be a part of any strict weak order comparator. That is left to the algorithm utilizing the comparator to determine by derivation, specifically when neither `(a<b)` nor `(b<a)` are true, the objects are considered equivalent.

Therefore, the comparator you should be using is simple this:

```
return b->get_distance() < a->get_distance();
```

That should provide the ordering you seem to want.